# Bootstrap select misplaced on Chrome and Opera?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I just noticed that the select from Bootstrap looks slightly misplaced when opened in Chrome and Opera on OSX:

[image]
[image]

I also tried in Firefox (which looks normal) and on Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Linux (which also looks fine). I unfortunately don't have a Windows machine to test on.

My main question is; why? And my second; how I can get these to align good again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look of the select dropdown menu depends only on browser styles. You can't change it via CSS. This has nothing to do with Bootstrap framework.

In order to have the same cross browser look of the select dropdown menu you can use some third party JavaScript/jQuery plugins like **[bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)** or **[select2](https://select2.github.io/)**.